# How to send the coordinates from android to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql

I have been trying to send the latitude and longitude from my simple android application to MySQL but yet no positive result.
This is my mainactivity class I want to know how I can take location as a parameter to send it to the sendcoordinates() method or if any other way is available.

```
package com.pawee.getlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String coord;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    Log.i("Location", location.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            };

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            }else{
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, locationListener);
            }

        }

    public void sendcoordinates()
    {
     //   name = ET_Name.getText().toString();
     //   user_pass = ET_Pass.getText().toString();
        String method = "location";
        geo backgroundTask = new geo(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,coord);
        finish();

    }
    }
```

This is the geo class which to send the parameters to the MySql database.

```
package com.pawee.getlocation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Ahmadzai on 7/12/2017.
 */

public class geo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    Context ctx;
    geo(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String coordd = "http://192.168.8.100:8081/geo/location.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("location"))
        {
            String coord = params[1];

            try {
                    URL url = new URL(coordd);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("coord","UTF-8") + "=" +URLEncoder.encode(coord,"UTF-8");


                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    OS.close();

                    InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    IS.close();
                    return "stored ....";

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

          //  return "Registration unsuccessful ....";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  ;
    }
}
```

In the database the data type of the column is geometry.
I would really appreciate if any of you help me in this regard or suggest me any better way to send the precise or one point location to the database. 
Thanks